# How to Install Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 Driver onto Linux Mint

Tags: drivers, wifi, broadcom

I had just recently downloaded Linux Mint onto my computer, and I downloaded a 64-bit driver for wireless, but I don't know how to install it.

I've never used linux before now, and the person who downloaded the software already left for vacation.

I understand the concept of opening a terminal and writing commands, from previous forums, but none of what I try seems to work.

I wrote */home/uname -r~/Desktop/broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0 2/kmod* and I get a reply saying *bash: /home/uname -r~/Desktop/broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0 2/kmod: No such file or directory*. But the file is on the desktop. I continued with writing */home/uname -r~/Desktop/broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0 2/kmod* which results in a reply saying *sudo: b43cutter: command not found*.

Another forum told me to go to: *System->Administrator->Additional Drivers(Hardware drivers)*. The only 'system' I have is: System Log, System Monitor, System Settings.

I'm not sure what to do. All the forums are confusing, and I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way. If you can have the internet access via an ethernet cable you can just install the b43 firmware

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and then load up the b43 module via

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

Now you should have wireless working

Answer (score 0):

The command you are entering is `/home/uname -r~/Desktop/broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0 2/kmod` - which is basically the wrong command, as the `uname -r` bit is to find the kernel version:

```
[wilf@comp ~]$ uname -r
3.11.8-200.fc19.i686.PAE
```

It needs to be `'/home/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop/broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0 2/kmod'` or `'~/Desktop/broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0 2/kmod'` (where `~` is your home directory's path)

Also, if you run `lshw -C network`, what shows up as the driver? (Under `driver=`) - It may be installed anyway.

You may also want to check `rfkill list` - you may also need to run it as root.

Comment: When I type in '/home/YOUR_USERNAME/Desktop/broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0 2/kmod' or '~/Desktop/broadcom-wl-4.80.53.0 2/kmod' it still tells me No such file or directory. :(

When I type in lshw -C network it says lshw-C: command not found.

And nothing happens when I type in rfkill list.

Comment: 'lshw' may need to be installed *(under Hardware lister in Software centre I think)* - but you could use `lspci -v`, but that would show everything on the PCI interface as well else as well. Remember to replace `YOUR_USERNAME` with **your username**. You may need to run `rfkill` as root, and that may need to be installed first.